# Kotlin: Problem with List Filter by Multiple Conditions

Tags: list, kotlin, filter

I'm trying to match two lists to another. In one list are items of crypto trades, the other contains so called candlesticks, which represents a price of crypto asset for one minute. A candlestick is limited by open time and close time. One trade item belongs exactly to one candlestick set. So I step through the trades list an for each item I apply a filter of two conditions. Unfortunately the filter returns no matching data. When I compare the trades data with candlestick items manually, I get a match. Here is the code of the data filter.

```
TradesDbHandler(dbConnector).use { dbHandler ->
    val rowsInTime = dbHandler.readTimeframe(startTime, buffer)
    rowsInTime.distinctBy { it.symbol }.forEach {

        val symbolFilter = rowsInTime.filter { row -> row.symbol == it.symbol }
        val symbolMinTime = symbolFilter.minByOrNull { it.time }
        val symbolMaxTime = symbolFilter.maxByOrNull { it.time }

        val tempKlines = binanceClient.getCandleSticks( symbolMaxTime!!.symbol, 
                                                        symbolMinTime!!.time, 
                                                        symbolMaxTime!!.time ) {
            log(">>> $it")
        }

        val klines = mutableListOf<KlineRow>()

            klines.plusElement(tempKlines.filter { row ->
                (row.opentime <= it.time) &&
                (row.closetime >= it.time) })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was not the problem but the data. Therefore no matches could be found. Thread can be closed.